# jdoc: include in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

Hi I am a newbie in Joomla and want to understand one of the functionalities of the Joomla.

In joomla templates we use

```
jdoc:include type="component"
```

statement. But I am not able to understand how this functionality has been implemented in Joomla. How passing the component name in url gets rendered by the above statement of Joomla ? Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from this sentence in [Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements):

> The **jdoc:include** statement is a Joomla! template's method of
>   displaying content specific to the page being viewed. There are
>   various **jdoc:include** statements, each returning a different part
>   of a Joomla! page. The replacement itself is done in
>   JDocumentHTML::_renderTemplate. See also _parseTemplate.

I've analyzed the *JDocumentHTML* class in `/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php` and it seems that Joomla loads the template and search in it for jdoc statements, with the **getBuffer** function retrieves the code to add instead of jdoc.

```
foreach ($this->_template_tags as $jdoc => $args){
    $replace[] = $jdoc;
    $with[] = $this->getBuffer($args['type'], $args['name'], $args['attribs']);
}
return str_replace($replace, $with, $this->_template);
```

The **getBuffer** function calls another render function to specifically load the correct component or module. For components the code is this:

```
$renderer = $this->loadRenderer($type);
...
$this->setBuffer($renderer->render($name, $attribs, null), $type, $name, $title);
```

Anyway at this point I got a little confused and cannot understand how the various renderers actually works, let's see if anybody else knows the trick.